# Python sqlite3 - sqlite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pygame, python-multithreading

Im using the Mastermind pygame library and I'm trying to send and recieve data from the server.

The error looks like this;

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\threading.py", line 637, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\threading.py", line 594, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Dropbox\Python\PythonRPG-Server\Mastermind\_mm_server.py", line 219, in run_forever
    self.server.callback_client_handle(self,data)
  File "server.py", line 54, in callback_client_handle
    register = self.db.register(data[1]['username'], data[1]['username'])
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Dropbox\Python\PythonRPG-Server\db.py", line 148, in register
    self.saveDB()
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Dropbox\Python\PythonRPG-Server\db.py", line 126, in saveDB
    self.conn.commit()
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 5072 and this is thread id 976
```

The register function is;

```
def register(self, user, password):
    """
    Register user to database
    """
    ###Check if user exists
    query = "SELECT password FROM accounts WHERE username = '%s';" % (user)
    qure = self.query(query)
    if not qure:
        hashe = sha256_crypt.encrypt(password)
        sql = "INSERT INTO acounts (username, password) values('%s', '%s');" % (user, hashe)
        self.query(sql)
        self.saveDB()
        message = "New user: " + user
        #alertMessageDialog(msg=message, title='Created!')
        return True
    elif qure:
        #alertMessageDialog(msg='User already exists', title='User exists')
        return False
    #cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (%s, %s)" % (user, hashe))
    #print(sha256_crypt.verify("password", hashe))
    #print(hashe)
```

At first I thought I created more than once instance to the server, but that still wouldn't affect the threading. So, what could be wrong? I've never worked with threading before so I'm completely stumped. I wouldn't even want to work with threading right now, but the library I'm using uses it so...

Comment: So the library calls your functions in different threads? Why do you need to use the same DB connection in all threads?

Comment: Server could create threads to serve more then one client at the same time.

Comment: Maybe if you put all SQLite code in `register()` and every thread create own SQLite object and connection ... ?

Comment: I second furas suggestion: open and close the database in register()